# How to count Core Data entities matching a query for one to many relationship?

Tags: ios, core-data, count, group-by, entity

Lets say I have 2 core data entities. A Student entity and a Class entity. For this example, a student is in exactly one class and a class can have many students.

Let's also suppose that these are big classes. That is, there are 1000's of students in each class.

The Class entity looks like:

```
NSString* name
NSArray* students
```

and the Student entity:

```
NSString* name
Class* class
NSString* grade
```

In my UI, I want to display a class. I want to show the *number* of students that have a certain grade. I.e. for a class of 1000 students, 50 have A's, 500 have B's 200 have C's... and so on.

Whats the most efficient way to get these counts from Core Data?

I'm current;y using an NSFetchedResultsController and passing it a fetch request for a group by + count query. I'm using the NSFetchedResultsController so that the UI updates as the number of students who have a certain grade changes. It's pretty slow though.

Is there a way to get this information without querying? I.e. as students are added to classes or their grades are changed, a property on the Class is updated with all the grade counts. So that when I want the counts, their are just a property of the Class and no query is needed.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can try this fetch request:

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Student"];
[request setResultType:NSDictionaryResultType];
NSExpression *keyPathExpression = [NSExpression expressionForKeyPath:@"grade"];
NSExpression *countExpression = [NSExpression expressionForFunction:@"count:" arguments:[NSArray arrayWithObject:keyPathExpression]];

NSExpressionDescription *expressionDescription = [[NSExpressionDescription alloc] init];
[expressionDescription setName:@"gradeTypeCount"];
[expressionDescription setExpression:countExpression];
[expressionDescription setExpressionResultType:NSInteger64AttributeType];
[request setPropertiesToFetch:@[@"grade",expressionDescription]];
[request setPropertiesToGroupBy:@[@"grade"]];
[request setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"theClass == %@",cls.objectID]];
```

This will result in an array of dictionaries holding the desired values.
The problem here will be that your FRC would not be able to track changes for those results. and therefore no reason to use a FRC in the first place
Even so, this is a very lightweight request and you could either issue it at a given time interval and update your UI.

> > (say 2 sec, and since you are not dealing with managed objects any more you can do the entire process in the background and dump your results to the main thread as you please)

Or listent to changes on your main context and if a student element changed, you refetch the counts again.

This will avoid fetching any `Student` elements all together (at the described cost).

Comment: if you are using FRC, add sort descriptors.

Comment: i ended up just using the group by fetch request you provided and then listed for changes to the moc to run the request again when needed

Answer (score 5):

You can use following example to get count in given condition. You don't need to fetch data for counting.You can use `countForFetchRequest` method to count the object efficiently .

```
    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    [request setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:entityName inManagedObjectContext:moc]];

    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
        @"grade=='A'"];
    [request setPredicate:predicate];

    NSError *err;
    NSUInteger count = [moc countForFetchRequest:request error:&err];
    if(count == NSNotFound) {
      //Handle error
    }

    [request release];
```

Comment: How would I monitor for changes to these counts? Also, what are the performance characteristics of countForFetchRequest vs a regular fetch?

Comment: You can use NSFetchrequstcontroller for countForRetchRequest same as fetchrequestcontroller. This is more efficient than regular fetch. You dont have fetch all data to get the count.

Comment: I don't think there is a method countForFetchRequest in the NSFetchedResultsController

Comment: Why not you  can monitor changes using fetchrequest controller. For exmaple controllerDidChangeContent delegate method.

Comment: I can do that, in fact that is what I am already doing. It's too slow however because you have to pass the NSFetchedResultsController and fetchRequest and it goes off and does the whole fetch of 1000's of Students. There is no way as far as I can tell to tell the NSFetchedResultsController to use countForFetchRequest

Answer (score 1):

Very simplest way in swift.

```
let request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "BWCoreDataNotification")
request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "type = 'purchase_reward'")

var error: NSError?
let numberOfNotifications = NSManagedObjectContext.MR_defaultContext().countForFetchRequest(request, error: &error)
```